# Import RSS in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, rss, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet that I want to use as a database for my Xcode app. I was wondering if anyone knows a tutorial I could follow in order to learn how to get the data from the spreadsheet as an RSS feed into my Xcode app?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else needs the answer to this question.

I was able to get the RSS feed of my spreadsheet by following the "Getting the Feed" section of this tutorial:
http://simile-widgets.org/wiki/How_to_make_an_exhibit_from_data_fed_directly_from_a_Google_Spreadsheet

Once I got the URL for the feed, I added "?hl=en_US&alt=rss" to the end of the URL for my NSXMLParser in xcode to be able to read the feed.